# How to apply new TLS certificates for running Hashicorp Vault service

Tags: docker, hashicorp-vault, vault

I am using Hashicorp vault , consul. So I have Vault,Consul and Golang Vaultmanager services. These services are running as a docker containers. I am not using any container orchestration (like k8s or podman). Simply running the containers in Linux environment using docker-compose.yaml file.

Refer the docker-compose file content below.

```js
 version: '3.6'

services:

  vault:
   
    image: imagename

    networks:
      - nwname
    
    command: server -config=/vault/config/vault-config.json
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
      
    restart: always
    
  consul:
    
    image: imagename

    networks:
      - nwname
    command: agent -server -bind 0.0.0.0 -client 0.0.0.0 -bootstrap-expect 1 -config-file=/consul/config/config.json
     
    restart: always
 
        
  vaultmanager:
    image: imagename
     
    devices:
      - "/dev/tpm0:/dev/tpm0"
    networks:
      - nwname
   
      
    restart: always
   
networks:
  nwname:
    name: nwname
    driver: bridge
```

For now Vault service is using Self signed certificates for TLS communication. But we need to update the certificates (.crt and .key). Once the containers are up and running, during the VaultManager service startup i am generating new certificates and put it into same location where the existing certificates were loaded.

So the Vault server needs to pickup the newly updated TLS certificates. How do we achieve this feature?

**Note**: Vault,Consul,VaultManager services are running in separate containers. From the VaultManager container we need to achieve this feature automatically without manual intervention.

VaultManager service is written in GoLang.

I have tried to restart the Vault container from VaultManager container by using `docker restart Vault` but

> docker command not found inside the VaultManager container.

Please refer the below vault-config.

```js
{
  "backend": {
    "consul": {
      "address": "consul:8500",
      "path": "vault/"
    }
  },
  "listener": {
    "tcp":{
      "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",   
      "tls_disable": 0,
      "tls_cert_file" : "/vault/config/certificate.crt",
      "tls_key_file" : "/vault/config/private.key"
    }
  },
  "ui": true
}
```

Also please advice, how can we use `SIGHUP` process in this usecase.

Comment: You need to tag "docker" for this post. The things you're asking about are NOT specific to Vault as an application.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you're trying to do here. Nothing you're asking here is unique to Vault, and is more a general sysadmin question. Also it is unclear which containerization platform you're leveraging.

First option is to SIGHUP the Vault process. For some config, this is sufficient for Vault to pick up and process the changes. If you've registered Vault as a systemd service, you can use `systemctl reload vault.service` command to send this signal.

Second option is to `systemctl restart vault`. This will incur downtime, and possibly require you to unseal (unless you have auto-unseal configured). Only use this if the SIGHUP doesn't work.

Third option is to send a `docker container restart vault` to the host. This assumes Docker - if you're using Kubernetes, or Nomad, or Cloud Foundry, or something else, you should put those details in your question. This will have some of the same drawbacks as simply restarting the service, and should only be used if your container runs a script on boot that is doing something important (which hopefully isn't the case).

If you're asking how to `ssh` from one container to another, you should add tags to your question, as this is beyond the scope of Hashicorp Vault.

Further reading:
https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/5767318985107-Vault-SIGHUP-Behavior

Comment: I have updated the question. Could you please read once. Let me know if any other inputs are required.

Comment: Mount host machine with docker container is not the best solution, like Docker inside docker.

Comment: @V.Periyasamy absolutely, I was suggesting something more along the lines of the docker container running an `ssh` command against the host machine, not nesting containers.